# Blowing down a divisor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an integral projective scheme (say, over the field of complex numbers). Let $D\subset X$ be a codimension one subscheme. Is there any simple way to decide, whether there is a birational morphism $f:X\to Y$ such that the codimension of $f(D)$ is greater than one? I don't care whether $Y$ is smooth or not.

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24503/contracting-divisors-to-a-point/24516#24516